# Losing path value after update complete in ajax file upload tool kit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following case;

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string c = hdntest.Value;
        Image1.ImageUrl = "somePage.aspx";
    }
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string c = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        string path = @"C:/temp/" + c;        
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

        hdntest.Value = path;
    }
```

In the above code, and when i inserting break point on upload complete event, i got 
the right value of my image path in the hidden field.
But when i watch the same value on button click it loses the path.
Please I need help about this issue.

Comment: Yes this is case with file upload control, as this file upload control making new request each time.

Comment: I post's the code that executed but i don't have onClientUploadComplete() java script function

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" ViewStateMode="Inherit" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Please try following answer and remove above comment with aspx code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as specified in the following code

In aspx page :

```
  <ajaxtoolkit:ajaxfileupload id="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
        onclientuploadcomplete="onClientUploadComplete"
        viewstatemode="Inherit" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Add following code in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onClientUploadComplete(sender, e) {
            var path = e.get_postedUrl();
            document.getElementById("hdntest").value = path;

            alert(path +'  ' + document.getElementById("hdntest").value);
        }
</script>
```

Make changes in the .cs file as follow:

```
       protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
       {
            string c = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
            string path = @"C:/temp/" + c;        
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

            //hdntest.Value = path;
            e.PostedUrl = path;
        }
```

Comment: Hello Bhavesh Kachhadiya, i'm sorry to say that but i'v got the same result, the hidden field doesn't have any value after button click, i don't know why, but i did the same as you suggest.

Comment: where is your hidden field reside?

Comment: I didn't understand you, but i guess in aspx not aspx.cs

Comment: can you debug your javascript code by alert to see what path you getting and value value of you hidden field?

Comment: see I have updated the javascript section to make verification

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

Add this javascript to set url to your hidden field **hdntest**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function onClientUploadComplete(sender, e) {
             document.getElementById('<%=hdntest.ClientID %>').value = e.get_postedUrl();
         }
</script>
```

This is how AjaxFileUpload should be

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server"> 
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" ViewStateMode="Inherit" 
                OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" /> 
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdntest" runat="server" />
            <br /><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px"/>
        </ContentTemplate> 
        <Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" /> </Triggers> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I put all controls in the same UpdatePanel and you have to add this propery into your AjaxFileUpload control: **OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete"**

In your code behide should be

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string c = hdntest.Value;
        Image1.ImageUrl = c;
}

protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ContentType.Contains("jpg") || e.ContentType.Contains("gif")
        || e.ContentType.Contains("png") || e.ContentType.Contains("jpeg"))
    {
        Session["fileContentType_" + e.FileId] = e.ContentType;
        Session["fileContents_" + e.FileId] = e.GetContents();
    }

    // Set PostedUrl to preview the uploaded file.         
    e.PostedUrl = string.Format("?preview=1&fileId={0}", e.FileId);
}
```

Finally, you have to handle the psted url in page_load event handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["preview"] == "1" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["fileId"]))
    {
          var fileId = Request.QueryString["fileId"];
          var fileContents = (byte[])Session["fileContents_" + fileId];
          var fileContentType = (string)Session["fileContentType_" + fileId];

          // To clear the current uploaded file, prepare to upload other files
          if (fileContents != null)
          {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = fileContentType;
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);
                Response.End();
          }
      }
  }
```